# _axios.default.post.mockImplementationOnce is not a function VuesJS

Tags: vue.js, axios, jestjs

I try to test my API Call.
I'm using:

1. VueJS
2. Jest
3. Axios

I received the error: "_axios.default.post.mockImplementationOnce is not a function" when I run this test:

```
import axios from 'axios'

let url = ''
let body = {}

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  //__esModule: true,
  post: (_url, _body) => { 
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      url = _url
      body = _body
      resolve(true)
    })
  }
}))

//axios.mockResolvedValue();

describe('getGameList', () => {
  test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', async () => {
    
    const response = {
      data: [ 
        { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
        { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
      ]
    };

    //axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response);
    //OR
    axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));

    expect(url).toBe("api/game_list_of_user")
    expect(body).toStrictEqual({"user_id": 1})

  });

});
```

Any clue ?

**Edit 1**: Following the help of tmhao2005:

```
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => { 
      url = _url
      body = _body
      return Promise.resolve();
    }),
  create: jest.fn(function () {
      return this;
  })
}))

describe('getGameList', () => {
  test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', async () => {
    
    const url = "api/game_list_of_user";
    const body = {
      "user_id": 1
    };   
    const response = {
      data: [ 
        { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
        { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
      ]
    };
    axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response); //OR axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));

    expect(url).toBe("api/game_list_of_user")
    expect(body).toStrictEqual({"user_id": 1})

    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  });

});
```

But I still have that problem:
[image]

It looks like my mock axios is not called. the toHaveBeenCalledTimes method is the correct method to call ?

**Edit 2**:
I called my action and try to mock my context.

```
let url = ''
let body = {}

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => { 
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      url = _url
      body = _body
      resolve(true)
    })
  })
}))

//https://medium.com/techfides/a-beginner-friendly-guide-to-unit-testing-the-vue-js-application-28fc049d0c78
//https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest
//https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-actions.html#testing-actions
describe('getGameList', () => {
  test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', async () => {
    //const commit = jest.fn()
    const MockContext = jest.fn(() => {
      let context= {
        state: {
          user: {
            id:1
          }
        }
      }
      return context
    });
    const response = {
      data: [ 
        { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
        { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
      ]
    };

    axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response); //OR axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));

    await actions.getGameList(axios.post, MockContext)
    expect(url).toBe("api/game_list_of_user")
    expect(body).toStrictEqual({"user_id": 1})

    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    //expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mutations.UpdateGameList, true)
  });

  test('Error: an error occurred', () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Error';
    axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage))
    );
  });

});
```

I have this error now:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```js
import actions from '@/store/actions'
import mutations from '@/store/mutations'
import state from '@/store/state'
import store from '@/store'
import axios from 'axios'

let url = ''
let body = {}

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => { 
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      url = _url
      body = _body
      resolve(true)
    })
  })
}))

//https://medium.com/techfides/a-beginner-friendly-guide-to-unit-testing-the-vue-js-application-28fc049d0c78
//https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest
//https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-actions.html#testing-actions
describe('getGameList', () => {
  test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', async () => {
    const context= {
      state: {
        user: {
          id:1
        }
      },
      commit: jest.fn()
    }
    const response = {
      data: [ 
        { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
        { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
      ]
    };

    axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response) //OR axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));
    await actions.getGameList(context)
    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith("api/game_list_of_user",{"user_id":1});
    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("UpdateGameList", response.data)

  });

  test('Error: an error occurred', () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Error';
    axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage))
    );
  });

});
```

Comment: The nested jest.mock and jest.fn did not work for me. Does not work for me: 
I got ```Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: [...path...]frontend/src/components/validation/SubmitForm.test.js: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: jest```
(your post still helped, I went for mocking all of axios, then mocking axios.post separately and got it working for me)

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, you are now mocking the `post` function with your own function which is not of type `jest.Mock`; that's why method `mockImplementationOnce` does not exist.

In other to fix this, you could either:

- return a mock function instead:

```js
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => {
    url = _url;
    body = _body;    
    return Promise.resolve();
  })
}));

// It looked like to forget call your action

import yourAction from "path/to/yourAction";

test('Success: ...', async () => {
  // ...  
  axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));

  // call your action
  await yourAction();
  
  // ...
  expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

- or, if you no longer care about `url`/`body`, you just simply mock `axios` without implement anything:

```js
jest.mock('axios')
```

Comment: thank you, it's working. But I still have a problem. it looks like the mock it's not called. I edited my question.

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. if `expect(url).toBe("api/game_list_of_user")` has been passed which means your mock has been called. Is there a working example there?

Comment: I used that link to wirte my mock fucntion: https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-actions.html#writing-the-test
I don't understand why my mock function is not called

Comment: The fact is you haven't called your action in your unit. I dropped you another hint to call it in the updated answer

Comment: okay Thank you for your help.
I called my action and try to mock my context
The error: "cannot read property context.state.user.id of undefined" 
Do I mock my context in a wrong way ?
I updated my post

Comment: You made it wrong. Just simply call `await actions.getGameList(context)`, it would be working then

Comment: `jest.mock('axios')`, that worked for me. The first suggestion failed for me, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65111164/axios-default-post-mockimplementationonce-is-not-a-function-vuesjs/65111728#comment128060899_65244577

Answer (score 0):

Just a little explanation for others:
You weren't supposed to pass axios.post to your action call. It has already been mocked. So whenever your action calls it, the mock will automatically pick the call instead.
Also when calling vue actions from the source obj e.g myStore.actions.myAction, you are supposed to pass the context as the first argument, not the second as that is what Vuex does behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

in case you need to have a specific responce in your mock this is how to do it

```
const mockedResponse = {
  data: { value: {key:val},
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  headers: {},
  config: {},
};

const mockedResponseEmpty = {
  data: { value: {} },
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  headers: {},
  config: {},
```

};

```
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    url = _url;
    body = _body;
    const found = body.filter.indexOf("Some_Text");
    if (found > -1) {
      resolve(mockedResponseEmpty);
    } else {
      resolve(mockedResponse);
    }
   });
  }),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add at the top jest.mock('axios')